# ActiveMQ session Id (STOMP)

Tags: session, activemq-classic, stomp

I created a durable subscriber using STOMP. When I reviewed my subscriber in "Active Subscribers" page for my topic in the ActiveMQ web console it has a session id "-1". What does this mean? Am I missing anything? My subscriber works though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an internal implementation detail of the broker.  The STOMP protocol does not have the idea of JMS sessions so the broker does not create anything other than a connection scoped internal session to convert between STOMP and the internal JMS style protocol handling that ActiveMQ implements.  You do not need to concern yourself with this value.